# Increment a Counter within a SQL SELECT Case Statement Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have some sample data that gives the following results:

```
**Name**
NULL
Bob
Steven
Jane

Susan
```

What should happen is the query should convert the NULLs and empty strings to a value of Anom[Counter], so it would end up like this:

```
**Name**
Anom1
Bob
Steven
Jane
Anom2
Susan
```

The basic query I have is the below, but how can I auto-increment the number?

```
select
    CASE WHEN Name is NULL or Name = '' THEN 'Anom1' Else Name END
from 
    Names
```

Sample data

```
Create Table Names
(
    Name varchar(50) NULL
)
insert into Names
(
    Name
)
select
    NULL
union all
select
    'Bob'
union all
select
    'Steven'
union all
select
    'Jane'
union all
select 
    ''
union all
select
    'Susan'
```

Comment: FYI: `case` is an *expression* not a *statement* (it might sound subtle, but its a massive difference in how it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` to generate the running number and `concat` to concatenate it with the string `Anom`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Name] IS NULL 
              OR [Name] = '' 
            THEN CONCAT('Anom', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULLIF([Name], '')
                                                       ORDER BY [Name]))
            ELSE [Name]
            END
FROM   [Names]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `row_number` like so

```
select IsNull(NullIf(Name,''),Concat('Anon', Row_Number() over(partition by IsNull(NullIf(Name,''),'Anon') order by Name) ) ) Names
from names
order by [name]
```